# I need help to implement cache in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i have to retrive some data from Db and should put it in cache.i have no idea on this and i am very basic learner of zend framework. i am using zend framework1.11.1 and wamp server. can any one help me how to start and how to proced are any tutoria.pls help me

Comment: Well, the obvious place to start would be the [docs for zend cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html).

Answer (score 1):

Zend Cache Provide a very simple way to store data in cache and to increase the speed. Zend uses Frontend and Back end to caching. Front end is useful to access or operate the cache. Back end is useful to store data in File , Memcache, Sqlite etc.

First of all Initialize the fronted and backed in bootstrap file by creating on function in bootstrap file.

protected function _initCache(){

```
$frontend= array(
    'lifetime' => 7200,
    'automatic_serialization' => true
);

$backend= array(
    'cache_dir' => '../application/tmp/',
);

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('core',
        'File',
        $frontend,
        $backend
);
Zend_Registry::set('cache',$cache);
```

}

then use the zend cache factory to define the cache object. The parameter core define the zend cache core means of generic type File parameter is to define the cache storage means where to store the records of cache then second and forth is for frontend and backend.

Now register that cache array using zend registry so that you can use that are in any controller , model etc.

Define Below code in any controller or any model where you want to use caching of data.

```
    $result1 =””;
    $cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');

if(!$result1 = $cache->load('mydata')) {
        echo 'caching the data…..';
    $data=array(1,2,3);
    $cache->save($data, 'mydata');
} else {
    echo 'retrieving cache data…….';
    Zend_Debug::dump($result1);
}
```

first of all in above code we get the cache array. Now if result one is not set then caching done means the file is generated at the path that you define in back-end array

For the Next time page load that data is retrieve from the file where the caching data store.

You can check the file as per defined path.

In that file data is in json format.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example about how Zend_Cache Works: You need a memcached system working on your localhost, or you can use a Backend_File to store cached items in files.

# Define this in your bootstrap

```
// configure caching frontend strategy
    $oFrontend = new Zend_Cache_Core(
        array(
    'caching' => true,
            'automatic_serialization' => true,
            'ignore_user_abort' => true,
            'lifetime' => 3600
        )
    );

// configure caching backend strategy
    $oBackend = new Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached(
        array(
            'servers' => array(
                array(
                    'host' => "127.0.0.1",
                    'port' => "11211", 
                )
            ),
            'compression' => true
        )
    );

// getting a Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page object
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory($oFrontend, $oBackend);

    Zend_Registry::set('cache', $cache);
```

#and then, in your controller you can use it as follows:

```
    $cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
    # save item in memcached
    $data = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $cache->save($data, "cache_name");

    # load item from your cache
    print_r($cache->load("cache_name"));
```

Then, you can see in Zend Framework Online Documentation all the frontends, backends and the available options in order to configure it for your specific needs.